# PHP Condition within a loop - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array like this:

```
$team_scores = array('Tigers' => 3, 'Spikes' => 6, 'Crashers' => 8, 'Fortress' => 2);
```

created from a MySQL query in which names are from one column and values are from another column. I want to create a page for each team that should indicate the name of the team and its score as well as position. So in this example I would have 4 pages and each page shows the name and score for a team without showing any information about other teams other than the total teams that participated. So it would show

> Name: Spikes  Score: 6 Position: 2/4,

For Crashers it would be

> Name: Fortress  Score: 2 Position: 4/4,

I am thinking a foreach loop would do but am only able to echo the teams and scores on a single page, when what I need is to create 4 pages, one for each item in the array. I am able to do that with data just being pulled from the database, but from such data I do not think its possible to determine the position of each team without having the data in one array.

Is that even possible or am I asking PHP to do what cannot be done? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it in PHP.  You want to use something like an ORDER BY clause in your SQL query to sort your results by score.  You can then use a LIMIT on the query to only fetch one row at a time, and combine that with an offset to get exactly the row you need.

Comment: That doesn't give you the position, does it?

Comment: Thanks @Obsidian. I am comfortable using the ORDER BY on the query but I don't think it will be able to tell at which position the score it has pulled from the db is. That is why I am thinking PHP may come to the rescue.

Comment: @Sylverdrag if you're going by offset in the query, you already know the position.  Trying to think of how to get it *without* the offset though...give me a bit.

Comment: @Sylverdrag okay nevermind, screw that netcoder posted a good solution below.  MySQL specific though.  /me goes to upvote

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you'd do:

```
SELECT 
   @position:= @position + 1 AS position,
   score_table.*
FROM 
   score_table,
   (SELECT @position := 0) p 
ORDER BY score;
```

Then you could do:

```
$count = count($results);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo "Name: {$result['name']}";
    echo "Score: {$result['score']}";
    echo "Position: {$result['position']}/{$count}";
}
```

If you want to do it in plain SQL (e.g.: compatible with other SQL databases), you'd do:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
   score_table
ORDER BY score;
```

Then, considering you have numerically indexed $results:

```
foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
    echo 'Position: '.($key+1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, does this assume or require that there is a column in the table for positions? I cannot recognize the syntax for the query!

Comment: @Bululu: No it doesn't. `@position` is a [MySQL variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: @Bululu if you add a unique ID for each team by the way, you can just use the first example @netcoder just posted, and only grab the data for the team that you're looking at the page of.  you just have to grab the data from something like _GET, typecast/escape it, and use it in your query to remove any need for iteration at all.

Comment: What goes at @position? I am familiar with the syntax like: "SELECT score_column FROM score-table"; so I could not see how to structure the query. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: @Bululu: Again, `@position` is a MySQL variable (link above). It is server-side (MySQL-side).

Comment: @netcorder, I Checked it! With my level of understanding of MySQL, I cannot query a DB that way. I am still a newbie, so the syntax looks complex to me. Again thanks for your efforts, I may still have a few months before I can go that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_GET to figure out which team to display:

```
/teams.php?team=spikes
...
$i = 0;
$nbTeams = count($team_scores)
foreach ($team_scores as $team => $score)
{
   $i++;
   if ($team == $_GET[team])
   {
       echo "Name: $team Score:  $score Position: $i/$nbTeams";
   }
}
```